# Extracting data from a complicated Json object

Tags: python, json

I am trying to fetch values from a particular json object in python. I have a csv file which I converted into JSON using json.dumps and my output looks like this:

```
['
{
 "name": "Tim","id" : 123344
}
','
{
 "name": "Alice","id" : 34544
}
','
{
 "name": "Roy","id" : 58888
}
']
```

I am trying to extract each name and id values from the above but can't seem to get the correct output.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I am using the following line to convert my csv to json: json_data = [json.dumps(d) for d in csv.DictReader(open('/tmp/Employees.csv'))]

Comment: He means the code you wrote that attempts to extract each name and if value from the JSON, and the output it produces, and why that output doesn’t satisfy you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the values in the dict don't use `json.dumps()`. Once you have read the file, you can loop through it to extract the `name` and `id`.

```
import csv
>>> with open('/tmp/Employees.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row['name'], row['id'])
```